# IIS Physical Path is not being respected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to get my Asp.Net Core 3.1 project running from inside Visual Studio on IIS.

I ran through the steps and it seems to run my Swashbuckle Swagger page, but it hits an error on finding the swagger.json file. When I look at the dev tools, I see I got a 404 when trying to load the swagger.json file.  The physical path it is trying to load from is:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\swagger\v1\swagger.json

But my code is not in inetpub, it is in my development folder.  What is even more odd, is I tried this on another machine and it works.  So it seems like it should be something to do with how IIS is setup.

I checked my IIS Site settings and the physical path is set to my development folder (not inetpub).  And when I hit the "Explore" option in IIS it loads my development folder.

I copied swagger.json into C:\inetpub\wwwroot\swagger\v1\ and it worked (though I then encountered other errors).

**Why is IIS trying to use inetpub to find the swagger.json file instead of my development folder?**

Comment: Have you published the asp.net core application in the inetpub or wwwroot folder? Is it possible to use the relative path when referencing the swagger.json file in the application, so it searches inetpub or wwwroot where the asp.net core application is located.

Comment: @Bruce Zheng - I have not published ever. I am just trying to get it to run in the debugger.

Comment: Without publishing, visual studio creates a virtual directory of asp.net core applications, and the corresponding physical path is in the inetpub directory.